# How to get Free Pascal working on Kubuntu 20

Tags: pascal

I can install Free Pascal on Kubuntu but programs won't compile - can't find system . . .
Lazarus is listed in Discovery but it won't install. Anyone got it running?

Comment: You must provide more details. Essential info:  What version of Kubuntu are you using? How are you attempting to install?  Where did you obtain the software?  What steps exactly have you followed and where exactly are you having a problem?  What is the exact problem?  Include all steps and all error messages unredacted and verbatim. Edit your question and make sure to avoid any ambiguity. Anyone reading should be able to reproduce the problem exactly from your description

Comment: Ubuntu has products that use the *year* format; eg. Ubuntu Core 20, which are *snap* only.  Kubuntu does not have such products, their products use the *deb* packages as a base thus are all *year.month* in format.  There is no Kubuntu 20 so you may have a *fake* or be running something else.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry that initial post was rather in haste. The version of kubuntu is kubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64. Lazarus DOES install from discover but when you try to run you get Can't find the lazarus executable /usr/lib/lazarus/2.0.6/lazarus.

Lazarus also installs fpc compiler but older version which generates spurious warning but you do get an executalbe file out of it.

Removed lazarus and installed fpc compiler from fpc-3.2.2.i386-linux.tar Chose /user/bin option at install. Can how run fp ide or use fpc compiler from konsole in home folder. So OK with command line pascal even if the visual lazarus environment not working.